# Why "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED" returns rows in different order?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, isolation-level

I am getting the rows in different order when I use

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

in my stored procedure.

Below is the query defined in the stored procedure.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

SELECT   CaseRateDetailId,AmtPerWeek
FROM    CaseRateDetails
WHERE   CaseRateInfoId = @CaseRateInfoId
```

It returns AmtPerWeek like this:

```
10000,15000,5000,20000,25000,..
```

When I run the same query without using

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

statement it returns the rows in the correct order i.e. `5000,10000,15000,20000,25000,....`

I can use the order by AmtPerWeek clause in above query but I want to know the reason why it is behaving like this? Why it is changing the order of rows?

Comment: There is no **correct** order without an order by clause.

Comment: No `ORDER BY` --> there is not defined or guaranteed or implicit order - if you need an order, you need to have an `ORDER BY` - **always.**

Comment: +1 for "but I want to know the reason that why it is behaving like this."

Answer (score 10):

Under `NOLOCK` or `TABLOCK` you can get an [allocation ordered scan](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/11/09/when-can-allocation-order-scans-be-used.aspx) which reads the pages in file order rather than following the leaf level of an index.

It doesn't show up in the execution plan whether or not it uses this method. Without `ORDER BY` no order is guaranteed.

Comment: That's fascinating - you are right it doesn't show up in showplan. Deleted my answer since you have proved it was wrong.

Comment: @Ben - When the plan shows an index scan with `Ordered:False` the relational engine indicates it doesn't care what order the rows are returned in, which means that the storage engine will consider this as a preferable option for indexes > 64 pages and where the data cannot change (tablock) or the isolation level is such that it prefers speed to any guarantee of consistency. Allocation ordered scans are much more likely to miss rows or read rows twice under conditions of concurrent data modifications than an index ordered scan.